# Custom URL for Post response in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url, post

I found few posts on this subject, however I would like to know the best practice to accomplish the following scenario:

I am willing to make a call to a 3rd party web service, that I will provide in my call few parameters, being one of them a POST callback to my website. The response will send me a token, that I should utilize on my following service calls.

I could send them (for example) a callback URL like this:

http://www.example.com/response.php

However, I was wondering how could I use an URL hiding my php file, like this:

http://www.example.com/Response/

I found few articles mentioning redirect, but there are many options on that, and since I'm new to Wordpress, I was wondering if someone with experience on this could give me some advice to be on track to make it the right way.

Sorry if this question was answered before, but I honestly found dozens and dozens of similar requests, but none of them that I found was clear as a best practice.

Many thanks!

Update:
I forgot to mention couple things:
1. I am planning to create a plugin from this, so it should be something that should be configured programmatically, while installing the plugin.
2. The URL that will be called by the remote client, is not a page, just an URL that will resolve into the php file with my code.

I hope it makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274668/wordpress-custom-post-url-query?rq=1

Comment: above link is useful tho you can create custom template from page section name 'response' and use as custom code in word press template.

Comment: Thanks Mirza and Ash. I didn't mention that I am planing to create a plugin from this, so I guess that manipulating a page template or the .htaccess when installing the plugin would be a challenge, wouldn't it? Based on what I read, what I should be looking for is a rewrite. What I do not understand is how to create a link to an URL that is not a page, make my code (in a .php file) to be called, so I could read the $_Post variable to process the response.

Comment: If you want to do this from within a plugin, then you should add the necessary rewrites from within your code; that’s what https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule is for.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, that seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I've got a plugin to integrate with a payment merchant, and it gets notification POST responses from the merchant. Looking through the plugin code, there is no rewrite rules around. I tried to trace the code, but I can't figure out how the code actually receives the POST response.
How to get a plugin to get a POST response, despite of the URL used?